# Подключение двух файлов Jquery, использующих функции друг друга

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два файла. Оба должны быть на jQuery. В обоих файлах функции из одного файла используют функции другого. По сути это разбиение огромного файла с функциями на 3-4 куска, где есть постоянное взаимное сообщение между двумя (или более) файлами.

Понятный упрощённый пример:
Файл **main.js** имеет вид:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       function hello () {
        alert ('Привет!');
    }

    the_beginning();
});
```

Эта функция **the_beginning()** описана в другом файле **func.js**:

```
function the_beginning () {
            hello ();
        }
```

Это основной смысл того как должна работать программа: несколько сотен функций из нескольких файлов типа   **func.js** указывают какой контент изменить. Они обращаются к файлу **main.js**, который меняет контент на экране.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением данной задачи. Спасибо!.

Comment: вынести общую логику в 3 файл?

Comment: Самый главный вопрос.. зачем вы разделили один файл на несколько? вам так кажется, что оптимальней будет загрузка в брузере? зачем делить файл?

Comment: @Arsen, Такая задача была поставлена из-за того, что файл с программой состоит из 7,5 тысяч строк кода.Было решено разбить его на куски по 500 строк, вынеся, как выше заметили, логику в отдельный файл.Таким образом, файлы-куски по 500 строк это все практические одинаковые функции по смыслу функции, но с разным содержимым (текст, картинки), эти куски должны по замыслу обращаться к файлу с логикой, который будет картинки,текст,кнопки и т.п. из этих функций подставлять в экран(в зависимости от действий пользователя).Т.е. это не про скорость загрузки приложения, а про оптимизацию большого файла.

Comment: @VanilJS, мне сказали, что это говнокод (пихать всё в один файл): "логику в отдельный файл, да и основные функции разбей на небольшие куски". В целом то я согласен с выносом логики в отдельный файл, только как его подключить на jQuery? Не переписывать же логику на ванильном JS... Должен быть прос той способ подключения доп. файла.

Comment: @ExtraCamelot вы чего, это серьёзно? "Было решено разбить его на куски по 500 строк,"  по вашему файл с кодом это новогодний торт который можно поровну просто поделить :) Кто вам такое задание дал, бухгалтер в офисе? Сразу скажу, что 7,5 т. строк - ничего страшного. Вы что, серьёзно думаете разбить один файл на 15 отдельных файлов? и это для вас оптимизация? Если дошло до того, что Вы бы хотели разделить логику, вы должны делить файл не по количеству строк, за такое светит - растрел!  Вы должны "прочитать" код и вырезать(сгруппировать) фукнции только по логике(!) их работы.

Comment: @Arsen, да дробление файла по 500, это я так выразился. Видимо некорректно... там функции будут объединяться по этапам работы с ними. Шут с ними. У меня основная проблема с выведением логики в отдельный файл. Как подключить второй файл на jQ, чтобы в него положить логику? Ванильный JS в отдельном файле работает, а jQ нет. Я вероятно не так определяю область jQuery во втором файле.

Comment: А как вы подключаете файлы? может у вас там конфлик идёт, откройте консоль браузера и посмотрите нет ли там ошибок?

Comment: @Arsen, а там ошибка, что не видит функцию. Т.е. во втором файле, так не видит 
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert ('Hello');
});
А, так видит (т.е. вне области jQuery) 
$(document).ready(function () {

});

alert ('Hello');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался... Моя ошибка была в следующем: когда я подключал второй файл я также делал в нём определение области jQuery как и в основном, т.е. писал так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // jQuery
});
```

А нужно было без обращения к документу сразу писать код на jQuery. В общем получился довольно глупый вопрос. Неопытность сделала своё дело. Спасибо за внимание тем, кто пытался помочь.
Надеюсь новичкам будет полезно.

Comment: Обратите внимание что jQuery не отдельный язык программирования, вы пишите код на js с использованием библиотеки jQuery. Так же как и использовать плагин слайдера, react или любую другую библиотеку, фрэймворк или плагин. Я на самом деле не сильно понимаю зачем его использовать вообще (но это из разряда демагогии)

Answer (score 1):

Если напишите функцию вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       function hello () {
        alert ('Привет!');
    }

    the_beginning();
});
```

Вы её не вызовете.
Сделайте две функции в разных файлах, подключите к странице и попробуйте вызвать в консоли браузера их.
Потом уже можно вызывать их как захотите

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    hello(); // возможна ошибка см. ниже
    the_beginning();// возможна ошибка см. ниже
});
```

Что то на подобии вот такого:

```
//file1.js
function func1(){
   console.log('funct1');
}
```

```
//file2.js
function funct2(){
   console.log('funct2');
}
```

```
//main.js
$(document).ready(function(){ // DOM построили но не факт что скрипты наши загрузились лучше $(window).load()
    func1();// !!Возможна ошибка если js файлы не загрузились еще
    func2();// !!Возможна ошибка если js файлы не загрузились еще
});
```

В случае вызова функции в функции вам необходимо ждать загрузки всех js файлов
желательно ждать выполнения `$(window).load()`